# Null pointer working with nodes

Tags: java, null

I have a problem comparing nodes (of binary tree) to `null`

Say node is a new root of the tree, with `key=5`.

In the constructor I set node's left, right and parent to be `null`

(fields: `private Node left=null,right=null,parent=null;`
constructor: `this.key=key`)

When I print the node's left child (same as for the right and the parent) `I get null` as expected.

However, `node.left==null` (or `node.getLeft()==null`) gets me `false`. why?

Here's the code of node class:

```
      public class Node{
        private Node parent = null, left = null, right = null;
        private int key; 

        public Node(int key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public Node getParent() {
            return parent;
        }

        public Node getLeft() {
            return left;
        }

        public Node getRight() {
            return right;
        }

        public void setParent(Node parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public void setLeft(Node child) {
            this.left = child;
        }

        public void setRight(Node child) {
            this.right = child;
        }

        public void setKey(int key) {
            this.key = key;
        }
  }
```

Comment: please post the code for the node class

Comment: Added it in the post

Comment: For this input:

Node n = new Node(5);
System.out.println(n.left +" "+n.right+" "+n.parent+" "+n.key);
System.out.println(n.left==null);

i get:

null null null 5
true

Same if i use the getLeft() method... How do you call it?